# How to serve build archived artifact in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins **Archive the Artifact** build post action to archive my build results. I am looking for a way to directly allow developers to download the archived artifacts from jenkins.

Is there any plugin support that?

Or is there any way to serve static resources through jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no plugins to install for that. When using **"Archive the Artifact"**, every build will generate a package so if developers need to download the artifacts they just need to go the concerned build on Jenkins then look at the **"Build Artifacts"** section and click to the artifact link that will propose them to download it.

[image]

For this to work, developers must have access to the Jenkins interface at least as read only mode.